# JAVA Swing: JPA controller function not return updated data from database

Tags: java, swing, jpa, jtable

I am using JAVA to build a panel with a `JTable` showing the information about books from sql server database. If I click a book button, this panel will display with data.

My problem is that, after the first display, if I change the modify data in database and re-click the book button (to reload the panel and display the change), the data does not change.

When I looked into the problem, I found that the function, which is responsible for retrieve data from database, return same result each click, though the data from database has changed.

This is the function (line 227 with breakpoint)

[image: picture1]

and what it does (this is **auto-generated** from JPA Controller, I do not modify anything)

```
        try
        {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(Books.class));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all)
            {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
```

My thought is that each time I click the button to reload the `JTable`, this function would be called to connect database and retrieved **current data** at db. In fact, though it is called and it still returns **old data**,not retrieve **current one** at db.

Can anyone explain this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same issue during one of my implementation in `spring-boot`.
I have solved the same using `entityManager.refresh(entity)`.

You need to refresh loaded dada using `EntityManager`.

The `EntityManager.refresh()` operation is used to refresh an object's state from the database. This will revert any non-flushed changes made in the current transaction to the object and refresh its state to what is currently defined on the database. If a flush has occurred, it will refresh to what was flushed. Refresh must be called on a managed object, so you may first need to find the object with the active EntityManager if you have a non-managed instance.

**Another solution** is to clear the cache using
`entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();`

This will empty the cache, and fetch objects changed outside the entity manager, it will do an actual database query instead of using the outdated cached value.

**Difference between evict and refresh**

`evict:` Mark an instance as no longer needed in the cache.
`refresh:` Refresh the state of the instance from the database, overwriting changes made to the entity

Comment: Thank you. I will try this, and will respond to your answer as soon as I get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Remember few things this is a classic case, where a snapshot of data is read by a thread and another thread updates the data, which results in data inconsistency. Hence any such sharing should be synchronized.
In your case a transaction is already in progress and someone modified the data from the database, hence you have to refresh everything again and then you shall see the modified data.

Comment: I do not quite understand your answer. In the code, after the query to database, the entity manager in the function will be closed . Is it not enough to refresh the **transaction** to get new database? If not, please advise how I should achieve this? Should I close entitymanagerfactory also?

Comment: Just one thing to clarify, I have not built a thread to insert or delete yet, I just use sql server to do this action manually to test the select data above. So there is no thread updates data for now.